# autocomplete : How can I change the result list with only elements that start with input-word?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myList = [ "Avellino", "Enna", "Frosinone" ];

    $("#myTextBox").autocomplete({
        source: myList,
        appendTo: "#myOwnMenuProvince"
    });    
</script>
```

Now, if I digit `e` I'd like to see only words in the list that **start with** `e`, not that contain `e`. So, in the example above, only `Enna`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the plugin uses the method `$.ui.autocomplete.filter`. This method does a grep using a regular expression on the label/value properties of the data and returns the filtered data. Let's inspire ourselves from that to make our filtering.

To use your own filtering method, use the `source` option as a callback.

- the `request` parameter is an object containing one property `term`. It contains the text to search for, basically the value of the input field. So if you type "en" in the input field, `request.term` will have that value.
- the `response` parameter is a callback. You call it, passing the filtered data, to display the data, basically show the results popup menu.

So basically, you would filter your data and pass the filtered array to the `response´ callback.

Here's one way to do it:

```
$("#myTextBox").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        // filter your data
        var data = $.grep(myList, function(value) {
            return value.substring(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase();
        });
        // pass it to the response callback for display
        response(data);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/yfwxL/)**

Comment: uhm...so request contain list (js objects? jquery objects?) of filtered data, that I should filter again? Not so clear! In fact I need standard functionality, plus a filter. Can you give a simple example?

Comment: I have re-phrased and made the filtering (as it seems you saw :o)